# Dynamically Create tables and Insert into it from another table with CSV values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Have a Table with the CSV Values in the columns as below

```
ID  Name    text    
1   SID,DOB 123,12/01/1990  
2   City,State,Zip  NewYork,NewYork,01234   
3   SID,DOB 456,12/21/1990
```

What is need to get is 2 tables in this scenario as out put with the corresponding values

```
ID  SID DOB 
1   123 12/01/1990  
3   456 12/21/1990


ID  City    State   Zip
2   NewYork NewYork 01234
```

Is there any way of achieving it using a Cursor or any other method in SQL server?

Comment: It's possible, but it's probably a lot simpler to write a script to parse the file, create the tables and `INSERT` the data. TSQL is very weak for working with text in general.

Comment: Better yet, if the report is for the single file only, parse the text and display the results.  It could probably be done with an excel macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways that this can be done. One way that I would suggest would be to split the data from the comma separated list into multiple rows.

Since you are using SQL Server, you could implement a recursive CTE to split the data, then apply a PIVOT function to create the columns that you want.

```
;with cte (id, NameItem, Name, textItem, text) as
(
  select id,
    cast(left(Name, charindex(',',Name+',')-1) as varchar(50)) NameItem,
    stuff(Name, 1, charindex(',',Name+','), '') Name,
    cast(left(text, charindex(',',text+',')-1) as varchar(50)) textItem,
    stuff(text, 1, charindex(',',text+','), '') text
  from yt
  union all
  select id,
    cast(left(Name, charindex(',',Name+',')-1) as varchar(50)) NameItem,
    stuff(Name, 1, charindex(',',Name+','), '') Name,
    cast(left(text, charindex(',',text+',')-1) as varchar(50)) textItem,
    stuff(text, 1, charindex(',',text+','), '') text
  from cte
  where Name > ''
    and text > ''
) 
select id, SID, DOB
into table1
from
(
  select id, nameitem, textitem
  from cte
  where nameitem in ('SID', 'DOB')
) d
pivot
(
  max(textitem)
  for nameitem in (SID, DOB)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ddc2b/8).  The recursive version will work great but if you have a large dataset, you could have some performance issues so you could also use a user defined function to split the data:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String1 varchar(MAX), @String2 varchar(MAX), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (colName varchar(MAX), colValue varchar(max))       
as       
begin      
    declare @idx1 int       
    declare @slice1 varchar(8000)  
    declare @idx2 int       
    declare @slice2 varchar(8000)     

    select @idx1 = 1       
        if len(@String1)<1 or @String1 is null  return       

    while @idx1 != 0       
    begin       
        set @idx1 = charindex(@Delimiter,@String1)  
        set @idx2 = charindex(@Delimiter,@String2) 
        if @idx1 !=0    
          begin
            set @slice1 = left(@String1,@idx1 - 1)   
            set @slice2 = left(@String2,@idx2 - 1)  
          end
        else  
          begin
            set @slice1 = @String1   
            set @slice2 = @String2
          end

        if(len(@slice1)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(colName, colValue) values(@slice1, @slice2)       

        set @String1 = right(@String1,len(@String1) - @idx1) 
        set @String2 = right(@String2,len(@String2) - @idx2) 
        if len(@String1) = 0 break       
    end   
return 
end;
```

Then you can use a CROSS APPLY to get the result for each row:

```
select id, SID, DOB
into table1
from
(
  select t.id,
    c.colname,
    c.colvalue
  from yt t
  cross apply dbo.split(t.name, t.text, ',') c
  where c.colname in ('SID', 'DOB')
) src
pivot
(
  max(colvalue)
  for colname in (SID, DOB)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3fae6/7)

Comment: Hi This Works perfectly fine but when you were doing cross apply (pivoting and inserting data) you had hard coded the column names i.e id,SID and DOB is there a way that i can dynamically pass them from source table ( I can do something like this `select distinct name from sourcetable`) and insert each row

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to approach this as a multi-step ETL project.  I'd probably start with exporting the two types of rows into a couple staging tables.  So, for example:

```
select * from yourtable        /* rows that start with a number */
where substring(text,1,1) in 
('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')  

select * from yourtable        /* rows that don't start with a number */
where substring(text,1,1) 
not in ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')

/* or simply this to follow your example explicitly */

select * from yourtable where name like 'sid%' 

select * from yourtable where name like 'city%'
```

Once you get the two types separated then you can split them out with one of the already written split functions found readily out on the interweb.

Aaron Bertrand (who is on here often) has written up a great post on the variety of ways to split comma delimted strings using SQL.  Each of the methods are compared and contrasted here.

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

If your row count is minimal (under 50k let's say) and it's going to be a one time operation than pick the easiest way and don't worry too much about all the performance numbers.

If you have a ton of rows or this is an ETL process that will run all the time then you'll really want to pay attention to that stuff.

Comment: Correction to this one, the code is comparing the Name column ("SID,DOB" or "City,State,Zip") to see if it is numerical or not, I think you meant to use the `text` column.  Also an easier way (in my mind) to find numerical strings is `WHERE SUBSTRING(<column>,1,1) LIKE '[0-9]%'` (or with `LEFT(<column>,1)` instead of the substring).

Comment: That works too - thanks for pointing out.  I forget about the range ability of like.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using cursors to build temporary tables. This has the limitation of making all columns VARCHAR and would be slow for large amounts of data.

```
--** Set up example data
DECLARE @Source TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(50), [text] VARCHAR(200));
INSERT  INTO @Source
        (ID, Name, [text])
VALUES  (1, 'SID,DOB', '123,12/01/1990')
,       (2, 'City,State,Zip', 'NewYork,NewYork,01234')
,       (3, 'SID,DOB', '456,12/21/1990');

--** Declare variables
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(200) = '';
DECLARE @Text VARCHAR(1000) = '';
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);

--** Set up cursor for the tables
DECLARE cursor_table CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT s.Name
  FROM @Source AS s
 GROUP BY Name;

OPEN cursor_table

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_table INTO @Name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --** Dynamically create a temp table with the specified columns
    SET @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE ##Table  (' + REPLACE(@Name, ',', ' VARCHAR(50),') + ' VARCHAR(50));';
    EXEC(@SQL);

    --** Set up cursor to insert the rows
    DECLARE row_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
     SELECT s.Text
       FROM @Source AS s
      WHERE Name = @Name;

    OPEN row_cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM row_cursor INTO @Text;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        --** Dynamically insert the row  
        SELECT @SQL = 'INSERT INTO ##Table VALUES (''' + REPLACE(@Text, ',', ''',''') + ''');';
        EXEC(@SQL);

        FETCH NEXT FROM row_cursor INTO @Text;
    END

    --** Display the table
    SELECT *
    FROM ##Table;

    --** Housekeeping
    CLOSE row_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE row_cursor;
    DROP TABLE ##Table;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_table INTO @Name;
END

CLOSE cursor_table;
DEALLOCATE cursor_table;
```